# Changing the home key behavior in an R session in emacs

Tags: r, emacs, dot-emacs

I would like to change the behavior of the home key within an R session run from emacs. When I press the home key, it takes me all the way to the `>` prompt. I'd like the home key to take me to the start of the command entry (i.e., two points in from the start of the line). I assume that I can make this adjustments via my `.emacs` file; any guidance for the commands that I would need to add to that file would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you have two requests, it's generally better to make two questions...

Comment: @Trey, Okay, sorry. I thought that they were similar enough to fall under the same heading. I'll edit.

Comment: I think these questions are so closely related you may as well keep it as a single question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you want is already available as `C-a`. You can rebind the home key with the following line:

```
(local-set-key (kbd "<home>") 'comint-bol)
```

There are a number of ways to get this to happen automatically when you are using the R session. I use something like the following:

```
;; Define the keybinding you want
(defun my-inferior-ess-mode-hook ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "<home>") 'comint-bol))

;; add the key-binding to the hook that gets called whenever you start an R session:
(add-hook 'inferior-ess-mode-hook 'my-inferior-ess-mode-hook)
```

That's a bit much for a single key-binding, but you can extend the definition of `my-inferior-ess-mode-hook` to include a number of customizations you'd like to use.